# View with sorting and paging

Tags: asp.net, sorting, paging

Is there any ASP view that has paging like listview and sorting like dataview?

I was trying to avoid the implementation of one of those two manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridView automatically implements these two abilities. Make sure the `AllowSorting` and `AllowPaging` properties are set to true. If you're using a sqlDataSource or objectDataSource the functionality is automatically taken care for your.

[GridView AllowPaging property description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx)

[GridView AllowSorting property description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx)

By default the GridView displays 10 records at a time but you can change that by setting the `PageSize` property.

Comment: Will AllowSorting and AllowPaging work with an object data source of type IEnumerable<ViewModel> ? 

Is it possible to choose which of the ViewModel properties I want to be sorted? 

eg: I have two properties and I want to have a button for each one of them so I can sort by them. I've seen examples with sql table sources but I'm not sure my source is valid for this, is it?

Comment: It works for ICollection, which is derived from IEnumerable, so my answer is probably not. Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough to make that a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something for ASP you're better off using a jQuery component. In ASP.NET, GridView does both, see this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx